# convering 00:33 to duration in golang

Tags: go

I have a string "12:34" that is "MM:SS" format and I want to convert it to a time.Duration. Wasted too much time on this already. What am I doing wrong in this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func parseDuration(input string) (time.Duration, error) {
    var layout string
    if strings.Count(input, ":") == 1 {
        layout = "04:05"
    } else {
        layout = "15:04:05"
    }
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, input)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return t.Sub(time.Time{}), nil
}

func main() {
    input := "00:04"
    duration, err := parseDuration(input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(int(duration.Seconds())) // I should get 4 but I get -31622396

}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/A-eHc-EPTrd

Comment: Time and duration are different things and "12:34" is a "time" and not a duration. Split into "12" and "34", strconv.Atio both, scale and add.

Comment: if input format is controlled by the program and it can be changed to something like `1m10s` , `time.parseDuration` may be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The zero value of type Time is January 1, year 1, 00:00:00.000000000 UTC.

```golang
func parseDuration(input string) (time.Duration, error) {
    var layout string
    if strings.Count(input, ":") == 1 {
        layout = "04:05"
    } else {
        layout = "15:04:05"
    }
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, input)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return t
}

fmt.Println(time.Time{})
// this prints 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
fmt.Println(parseDuration("00:04"))
// this prints 0000-01-01 00:00:04 +0000 UTC
```

In your case, you should define a `start` object instead of using `time.Time{}` directly. For example,

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var origin = time.Date(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

func parseDuration(input string) (time.Duration, error) {
    var layout string
    if strings.Count(input, ":") == 1 {
        layout = "04:05"
    } else {
        layout = "15:04:05"
    }
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, input)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return t.Sub(origin), nil
}

func main() {
    input := "00:04"
    duration, err := parseDuration(input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(duration.String()) // this prints 4s

}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/maGeyA0KWd3

Comment: Thank you for catching the problem - The origin was what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the line return t.Sub(time.Time{}), nil. You're subtracting the zero value of time.Time from t, which is equivalent to subtracting the Unix epoch time from t.

To get the duration from the string, you should use time.ParseDuration() instead:

```
duration, err := time.ParseDuration(input)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(int(duration.Seconds()))
```

This will correctly parse the duration in the string, and you'll get the expected output of 4.

Comment: `time.ParseDuration` cannot parse the format `"00:04"`. It can parse `"00m04s"`. If you want to use `time.ParseDuration`, you'd need to transform the input string first (split string by colons, add "h", "m" and "s" suffixes as needed, and recombine)